# Cannot add Long-Term Backup Rention to Sql Azure Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, database-backups

I don't have "Long-Term Backup Retention" in my list of properties on the left side for my Azure SQL database or database server even though I have added a "Backup Service Vault" in the same data center with the same resource group. I am not able to setup the [SQL backup to long term retention](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-sql-database-now-supporting-up-to-10-years-of-backup-retention-public-preview/) steps from Microsoft. How can I get "Long-Term Backup Retention" to be available for my v12 database?

Answer (score 0):

How do I enable Long-Term Retention?
To configure long-term backup retention for a database:

- Create an Azure Recovery Services vault in the same region, subscription, and resource group as your SQL Database server.
- Register the server to the vault
- Create an Azure Recovery Services Protection Policy
- Apply the protection policy to the databases that require long-term backup retention

Taken from: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-long-term-retention/

Comment: FYI for everyone, the `Long-term backup retention` menu is in the SQL servers section NOT in SQL Databases

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the following article for a Step by Step process for configuring and saving the Long-term retention plan for a given SQL Server and it's databases and save those backups in a Azure Backup and Recovery Services vault.

https://praveenkumarsreeram.com/2016/11/13/azure-backup-and-recovery-services-configure-long-term-retention-up-to-10-years-for-azure-sql-database/

Please note that you can see the backups after a week.

Thanks,
Prawin